# What is the difference between using "of=/dev/sdX" and "of=/dev/sdXY" in dd

Tags: partition, dd

First of all, this question is NOT the duplicate of [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/532653/difference-between-of-dev-sdx-and-of-dev-sdx-when-using-dd-command-on-debian-1), which compares lower-case "sdx" with mixed-case "sdX". Back to the question.

If I have a formatted memory stick which is composed of only a **single** partition and I use the following

```
dd if=input_file of=/dev/sdXY bs=ZZ ...
```

How will it be different from using

```
dd if=input_file of=/dev/sdX bs=ZZ ...
```

The question came to my mind because when i had to make a bootable Linux USB, I had to mention the drive number and NOT the partition number i.e.

```
dd if=Linux.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=ZZ ...
```

Would be glad if someone can explain the difference while considering one single partition drive/stick etc.

Comment: There are important 'files' on the harddrive outside of the partition, such as the master boot record (or MBR for short).

Comment: Partition table and the partitions it contains is a data Structure, stored on a storage device. You just needs to know what the data structure looks like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most ISOs nowadays are "hybrid ISO" images containing CD/DVD boot code ([El Torito standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Torito_(CD-ROM_standard)), 
an extension to the [ISO 9660](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660) CD-ROM standard) and 
an [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) (including boot code). This makes them bootable from CD/DVDs or USB storage devices.

By copying the ISO to the device (and not a partition), you create a USB bootable version of the ISO (like the read-only version on optical media) including 
MBR and partition(s).

If you copy an image to a partition, you generally copy a "partition image" (without MBR / [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table)).